# How to test the send method from a Kafka Producer with callback using mockito?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, mockito

I am trying to test a method and for that I am using mockito. However, my mock is not getting inside into the if's  condition and goes directly to the flush's line.

I would like to test the follow situation:

```
public class SomeClass{
     @Autowired
     private Producer<String, SpecificRecord> producer;

     private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.Factory.getLogger(SomeClass.class);

     public void sendMessage(String topic, SpecificRecord message, Map<String,String> headers){
         ProducerRecord<String, SpecificRecord> avroMessage = new ProducerRecord<>(topic, null, null, "key",message, headers);
         producer.send(avroMessage, (metadata, exception) -> {
             if(exception == null ) {
                 LOGGER.info("OK");
             }else{ 
                 LOGGER.info("NOK");
             }
         });
         producer.flush();
    }
```

And what I'm doing is it:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SomeClassTest{
    @InjectMocks
    private SomeClass someclass;
    
    @Mock
    private Producer<String,SpecificRecord> producer;

    @Mock
    private SpecificRecord message;

    @Mock
    private Logger logger;

    @Test
    public void sendMessageTest(){
        when(producer.send(any(ProducerRecord.class),any(Callback.class))).thenReturn(null);
        doNothing().when(producer).flush();
        
        someclass.sendMessage("topic", message, new HashMap<String,String>());
        verify(logger).info("OK");
    }
}
```

What can I do to mock this situation correctly?

Comment: Kafka includes a MockProducer class that you should probably be using instead

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/kafka-mockproducer

Answer (score 2):

By using the lambda expression below, you are implementing the **onCompletion** method of the **Callback** interface ([Interface Callback](https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/Callback.html))

```
(metadata, exception) -> {
         if(exception == null ) {
             LOGGER.info("OK");
         }else{ 
             LOGGER.info("NOK");
         }
     }
```

And since you are mocking the KafkaProducer send method call, that callback won't be called.
So, to be able to get inside the callback call, you have to capture the Callback argument and call the **onCompletion** method as below:

```
    ArgumentCaptor<Callback> callBackCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Callback.class);
    Mockito.verify(producer).send(any(ProducerRecord.class), callBackCaptor.capture());
    Callback kafkaCallback = callBackCaptor.getValue();
    kafkaCallback.onCompletion(new RecordMetadata(null, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), null);
```